# PuTTY displays unreadable characters

Tags: ssh, putty

As you can see below in the image, when I use PuTTY it displays these unreadable characters. I have been Googling forever but not yet found the answer, so I thought maybe someone on SO knows this. All settings are unchanged in this program. I have tried many SSH clients; all do this. Is this something with Windows?

[image: PuTTY displays unreadable characters]

Comment: That doesn't look like PuTTY. Why does the window title say "mRemoteNG"?

Comment: It is just a wrap around Putty system. I have also used the Putty app, makes no difference as the system behind it is the same.

Comment: OK, In Putty's settings, under Window, Translation what is the value of Remote character set? What is the value of Font in Window, Appearance? What happens when you cut the illegible text and paste it into Notepad?

Comment: charachters set is UTF-8. And you're on a good track - if i paste the charachters in notepad - i can see normal text.

Comment: What about the Font? What happens when you set Notepad's font to the same as Putty's?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what the font of putty is..

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one (or perhaps more) of the following:

- bad font
- display driver problem (perhaps for a specific font?)
- incorrect character-set encoding (UTF-8, Big8, CP866 ...)

If the text displays OK when cut and pasted into Notepad, it confirms this. Set PuTTY to use the same font and encoding as Notepad (at least initially).

Since everything works at a different location you probably need to copy settings from there and use a Font that works in Notepad.

To see Putty's Font, Right click the top left icon in Putty Window title-bar

[image]

Then select `Change Settings ...`

[image]

If mRemoteNG is getting in the way of seeing Putty settings, stop using mRemoteNG until you have everything working in plain unadorned standalone normal unviolated Putty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Putty with SerialCable . You are maybe using a wrong Baudrate.

But if you are using it for SSH, you can try TeraTerm for checking if it is a Putty- or a Hardware-Problem.

Comment: I have no idea what All these terms mean..TeraTerm is software to check this ? Could you explain maybe in more detail what you mean by this ?

Comment: I am Austrian so maybe my english is hard to understand.
At first i want to know, how you are connecting? Serial, SSH, Telnet etc.? 
If you are connecting over serial - maybe the baudrate (speed) is wrong.
If you are using SSH - what i think, cause you have the tag SSH, you could use teraterm. It is also a SSH-Client and if it works with this client, you know some settings aren't set correctly in putty. You also could try another notebook - but maybe your Server/PC which are connecting to has some problems. I don't think it is a Windows problem.

Comment: I am connecting via SSH and I have tried many SSH clients. Alle give these strange charachters. On my pc at work everything works, but at home it doesnt. Same server...